# IOS 7 date Format creat Event doesn't work

Tags: ios, calendar

I have a Problem with the Date Format in IOS 7 I have following code written:

```
// eventstart = "12.NOV.2013 13:45" is a NSString
// eventend = "13.NOV.2013 14:12" is a NSString

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:gmt];
[dateFormat2 setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat2 dateFromString:eventstart];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:eventend];
```

now I set the Event like:

```
    if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])

{[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (error)

            { }

            else if (!granted)

            { }

            else

            {           
               event.startDate = date;
               event.endDate   = date2;
               event.calendar  = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
               NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_type_s];
               event.title     = title;
               NSString *location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",_from_s,_to_s];
               event.location  = location;
               NSString *notes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"in GMT: \n %@ \n to \n             %@",_starttime_s,_endtime_s];
               event.notes     = notes;
              [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
              NSError *err;
              [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
 }
});
}];
```

THe Problem is that it works on the Simulator but not on the Iphone itself!
I think I have a Problem with the Date Format because date ord date2 is always nill in the debugger.....

Can Someone helps me with that problem or give me Tips to solve the problem!

Best Regards
Gert

Comment: The input string `"12NOV2013 13:45"` does not match the date format `"dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"`. Please have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i, or the zillions similar NSDateFormatter questions.

Comment: sorry my mistake but the code in xcode is correct only the question was written wron :-)! I edit my post but it doesn't work! THe dot is not the Problem!

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe the problem can be due to completion block which doesn't see your `date` and `date2`. Have a try with `date` and `date2` declared in your class @interface or @implementation. You can also try to create your dates in the completion block.

Comment: hmm that could be the problem .... but the code works on the simulator fine, only on iphone is no event saved.... hmm I will check it if I'm at home, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this as date format:

```
[dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"dd.LLL.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

That should fix the problem.